# click on second ambiguous link with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara

I want to click on the second of the two following links:

```
<a href="photo/1">photo</a>
<a href="photo/2">photo</a>
```

As you can see, the URLs are actually different, but the link title, "*photo*", is the same in both. *I am **not** using IDs on my links, and there is no nesting class context by which to distinguish the links.*

Ideally, I would like to be able to click even a third, or `nth` ambiguous link.

An example of a DSL for this purpose would be something like:

```
click_link photo.title, match: 2
```

Answer (score 3):

I find that using `all` is easier to read than locating by xpath:

```
all('a', :text => 'photo')[1].click
```

However, it not as fast as using xpath.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use xpath for this. Something like:

`find(:xpath, '//a[text()='photo'][2]').click`